# Could not find any factories that implement 'org.apache.flink.table.delegation.ExecutorFactory' in the classpath

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to execute table API for flink and getting the below error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any factories that implement 'org.apache.flink.table.delegation.ExecutorFactory' in the classpath.

I have checked multiple threads regarding this and seems all dependencies required. In one of the other project this same configuration working in Intellij however in the new project that I have created with same dependencies is not working

Below is the pom dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>F1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0-1.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-kafka-base -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka-base_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-base</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner-blink_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-datagen</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-table-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-table-planner-loader -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for Intellij , we have to select the java file -> edit Run configuration -> modify options -> Add dependencies with provided access to the classpath

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is done without the introduction of the planner dependency, just by introducing it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-table-planner_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
```